# JSON validation using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have an instance where i need to validate an uploaded JSON file in the client side (i.e angularJS).

When a user uploads a JSON file. I need to validate the fields in the JSON, like

```
{"name":"Rohith"}
```

If this JSON is uploaded then I will have a schema such as

```
{"field":"name", "type":"String"}
```

I saw it can be done by ajv. But did not find any suitable examples with angularjs. Is there any other plugin which can do this?

Comment: This angular plugin helps in validating the json.. https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form

Comment: @SpreeTheGr8 I am not validating a form. I'll upload a JSON file. Is that possible with that?

Comment: Are you saying you want the server to validate the JSON instead of your client js code?

Comment: No on the client side itself!